# root is not able to change permission of folder/files

Tags: vps, godaddy

I need to your help . I am trying to  changing  the  folder/files permissions but it is not working . what is the issue ? i am login on putty with root user.

Please help me .

Comment: You should at least provide the commands you are using and the error messages or results you get. `ls -aslh` for the folder you are processing and also add the results of your `chmod` command.

Comment: @EsaJokinen   I am trying chmod -R 077 /folder " error is operation is not permitted.

Comment: The edit to your question completely changed what the question is about. Neither of the versions contains even remotely enough information to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to verify the permission of the folder with:

```
lsattr /folder
```

If you see, you can't modify your folder, you can use *chattr* to remove the security. Answer will be probably more interesting if you tell us the name of your folder.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check that you are trying to change the right directory.  `/folder` points to the folder in the root directory of the server. root directory might not be the path you are in.

So `stat folder` should show you Uid and Gid of the directory. Uid has to be your user.

But why do you want to do a recursive chmod on a directory taking away the owners access rights? This will never work with a regular user as he will not be able to change anything within the directory And it seems that the system starts top down.

You can do this while you are root. But still I don't get the rationale behind that.